# Postgresql-Postgis : grouping pairs of id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I use Postgresql 9.6

I have a table with rows of data. Let's call it TABLE1. TABLE1 has a pkid column (a serial primary key).

Actually, each row is a building and the grouping operation is based on whether the buildings touch each other or not (the DB is with the PostGIS extension).
Now, my problem is not detecting when two buildings touch other, but recording the pairs in a temporary table.

I extract a sub-set of them using a SELECT sub-query (lets' call it subquery1) and I need to group them according to a certain criteria.
Subquery1 returns a set of rows with two columns, pkid_bat1 and pkid_bat2, the pkid of 2 different rows of TABLE1 that are associated together (based on a JOIN that uses a PostGIS function).

I'll take an example to make things clear :

Let's say I have 3 buildings that touch each others : A, B and C. 
Subquery1 will return 6 rows as pairs of pkid :
A-B, B-A, A-C, C-A, B-C, C-B.

To record that these 3 buildings are associated together, I actually only need 2 pairs, such as : A-B and A-C.

So what I have done so far is : after subquery1, I have nested another SELECT sub-query (subquery2) that for each of the 6 rows, returns as first column the min of the two pkid and as the 2nd column, the max of the two pkid and added a DISTINCT clause.
Thus, the 6 rows A-B, B-A, A-C, C-A, B-C, C-B become 3 rows : A-B, A-C, B-C.

I still need to get rid of the row B-C.

After subquery2, I have yet another nested subquery (subquery3) that does a self-join on the results of subquery2 :

```
SELECT mpb1.pkid_bat1 , mpb1.pkid_bat2
FROM resultsSubQuery2 AS mpb1
LEFT JOIN resultsSubQuery2 AS mpb2
ON mpb1.pkid_bat1 = mpb2.pkid_bat2
WHERE mpb2.pkid_bat2 IS NULL
```

This works : from the rows A-B, A-C and B-C, it will only keep A-B and A-C because A is never among pkid_bat2 (thanks to using the min and max functions in subquery2).
But it takes too much time.

**Is there another way to deal with this kind of problem (creating sets of pkid) ?**

---

Edit:
The whole code is there with a small change in subquery2 to replace the use of DISTINCT + min and max with the more simple use of a '<' in the WHERE clause:

```
WITH isolatedPonctualBuildings AS
(   
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (bat.pkid)
        bat.pkid, bat.pkid_emprise, bat.origine , bat.origine_id, bat.geom  
        FROM Temp_batiments_sites AS bat
        LEFT JOIN Temp_recoupements_bâtiments AS recoup
            ON bat.pkid = recoup.pkid_batiment2
        WHERE bat.type_geometry = 'Point'
        AND recoup.pkid IS NULL 
), 
matchedPonctualBuildings AS
( 
    SELECT 
        bat1.pkid AS pkid_bat1, 
        bat2.pkid AS pkid_bat2 
        FROM isolatedPonctualBuildings AS bat1
        JOIN isolatedPonctualBuildings AS bat2
            ON bat1.pkid_emprise = bat2.pkid_emprise 
            AND ST_Intersects (bat1.geom , bat2.geom) 
            AND ( bat1.origine != bat2.origine OR bat1.origine_id != bat2.origine_id )
        WHERE bat1.pkid < bat2.pkid 
)
    SELECT
        mpb1.pkid_bat1 , mpb1.pkid_bat2
        FROM matchedPonctualBuildings AS mpb1
        LEFT JOIN matchedPonctualBuildings AS mpb2
            ON mpb1.pkid_bat1 = mpb2.pkid_bat2
        WHERE mpb2.pkid_bat2 IS NULL
```

Comment: Instead of throwing away a random spatial relationship (A-B and A-C does not imply B-C; why not rejecting A-B or A-C instead?) and keeping others, wouldn't it be more suitable to keep the distinct IDs part of the relationship (so A-B-C)?

Comment: I guess I was not clear enough. In my example, I am not saying that A-B and A-C implies B-C, only that I may have a case with A-B, A-C and B-C.

Now, the origin of the problem is that subquery1 returns the associations as pairs. If it could return directly the association as A-B-C, I would not have to handle all this.

Answer (score 0):

Even tough I'm sure you could eventually find a SQL-only solution to this problem (using hierarchical queries most likely), I think it's a lot simpler to use procedural logic to filter the excess rows.

A simple logic in your application will be far more efficient than trying convoluted (and very slow) SQL.

You just need to retrieve the rows in a simple orderly manner.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not helping as this part has to be accomplished on the PSQL server.